# Extract href attribute from HTML text in Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-parsing

I have about 3000 rows in my Google Spreadsheet and each row contains data about one article from our website. In one column (e.g. A:A) is stored formated text in HTML. I need extract all URLs inside `href=""` attribute from this column and work with them later. (It could be array or text string separated with coma or space in B column)

I tryied to use `REGEXTRACT` formula but it gives me only the first result. Then I tryied to use `REGEXREPLACE` but I'm unable to write proper expression to get only URL links.

I know that it is not proper way to use regex to get anything from HTML.  Is there another way to extract these values from HTML text in one cell?

Link to sample data: [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WEGkho_oJJnsi8LTVcCNCQKXmzgWPCQJWyXOMsVQDbU/edit?usp=sharing)

Thak you in advance! I'm real newbie here and in scripting, parsing etc. too.

Comment: https://regex101.com

Comment: Thank you, but normal regex used in Google Spreadsheet is little bit different and not everything is working. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this samples? I used `href=\"(.*?)\"` for retrieving the URL. The sample of regex101.com is [here](https://regex101.com/r/c4pODV/1).

### 1. Using Google spreadsheets functions :

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(a1,">"),"href="&CHAR(34)&"(.*?)"&CHAR(34)))))
```

In this case, since `REGEXEXTRACT` retrieves only the first matched string, after the cell data is separated by `SPLIT`, the URL is retrieved by `REGEXEXTRACT`.

#### Result :

[image]

### 2. Using Google Apps Script :

```
function myFunction(str){
  var re  = /href=\"(.*?)\"/g;
  var result = "";
  while ((res=re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    result += res[1] + "\n";
  };
  return result.slice(0,-1);
}
```

This script can be used as a custom function. When you use this, please put `=myFunction(A1)` to a cell.

#### Result :

The result is the same to above method.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thak you very much! This helped! I didn't know, that I can use `SPLIT` inside `REGEXMATCH`!

Comment: @Břeťa Welcome. Thank you, too. I'm happy I could be useful for you.

Comment: @Tanaike is there a way we can have the function show every new slice in the next cells instead of all in one cell? For example if there are 10 links, I'd like it to show in 10 cells going down rather than 1 cell.

Comment: @sojim2 Although I'm not sure about your detail situation, if you want to split the retrieved URLs to cells with the row direction, how about `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1,CHAR(10)))`. In this case, the text data including URLs and above formula are put in the cell "A1" and "B1", respectively. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is the exactly the result I'm looking for and didn't know existed, thank you